# Php cURL returns location.replace with a relative address, how to change?

Tags: javascript, php, curl, authentication

I'm trying to login into a webpage using cUrl and this is the code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields)); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Running the script with the browser it returns a 404 Error but running the script with shell it returns "location.replace" containing a relative path (then executing the script on my server it can't find the location).

This is what cUrl returns:

```
<html>
<head><script>location.replace("main.php?email=xxx%40xxx.xx&lang=it")</script></head>
<body>
<!--pre></pre-->
</body>
</html>
```

So, can I change the location? I've already tried to switch `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`to false but nothing changes.

Can anyone help me?

Greetings

Comment: I don't get it. If you paste the contents of ``$url`` into your browser and hit enter you don't get 404?

Comment: No, if I paste the $url into the browser it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` will just make curl to follow all redirects made on the server side. It has no impact on the response string.

I would make my login script return something more useful than html/JavaScript redirect. Consider doing something like this

loginscript.php

```
$aReturn = array();
$bLoginSuccessfull = true;
if ($bLoginSuccessfull) {
    $aReturn['url'] = 'main.php?email=xxx%40xxx.xx&lang=it';
} else {
    $aReturn['error'] = 'something failed during login process';
}
$aReturn['success'] = $bLoginSuccessfull;

echo json_encode($aReturn);
exit;
```

And your curl-call

```
<?php 
$sUrl = 'http://mysite.it/loginscript.php';

$rCh = curl_init();
curl_setopt($rCh, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($rCh, CURLOPT_URL, $sUrl);
curl_setopt($rCh, CURLOPT_POST, count($aFields));
curl_setopt($rCh, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $sFields);
curl_setopt($rCh, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $sCkfile);
curl_setopt($rCh, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($rCh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$sResponse = curl_exec($rCh);
curl_close($rCh);

$sResponse = json_decode($sResponse);
if ($sResponse['success']) {
    // Send user to url (main.php?email=xxx%40xxx.xx&lang=it)
    header('Location: ' . $sResponse['url']);
} else {
    echo "Login failed...";
    echo $sResponse['error'];
}
```

If you can't change your login script for some reason then use regexp to match your response, something like this

```
...
$sResponse = curl_exec($rCh);

preg_match('/location.replace\("(.+)"\)/', $sResponse, $aMatch);
header('Location:' . $aMatch[1]);
```